# Поиск значений среди нескольких таблиц?

Tags: sql

Есть таблица ордеров:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    id INT,
    userId INT
)
```

Например, с такими значениями:

```
INSERT INTO `orders` (`id`, `userId`) VALUES (1, 10), (2, 10), (3, 10)
```

Есть таблица бонусов:

```
CREATE TABLE bonuses (
    id INT,
    userId INT
)
```

Например, с такими значениями:

```
INSERT INTO `bonuses` (`id`, `userId`) VALUES (1, 10), (2, 10), (3, 11), (3, 10)
```

**Задача:**

Мне необходимо выполнить группировку по количеству ордеров на пользователя.
Сделал так:

```
SELECT `userId`, COUNT(*) AS `order_counts` 
FROM `orders` 
GROUP BY `userId` 
HAVING `order_counts` >= 3
```

И достать тех пользователей, у кого количество ордеров больше или равно, чем бонусов. (ЭТО НЕ МОГУ)

Исходя из примера: Пользователь с `userId` 10 имеет 3 ордера (`order_counts`) и 3 бонуса (`bonuses_counts`). Хочу увидеть его после выполнения запроса. Ну, также, может быть юзер, который имеет 5 ордеров и, например, 4 бонусов, в выборке он тоже должен быть. А у если ордеров 10, бонусов 12 - нет.

Минимальный пример: [тыц.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=18c07856d376db721492d1f28e1ae0f7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точно так же групируйте заказы и потом делайте join по нужному условию:

```
SELECT oc.`userId` FROM (
  SELECT `userId`, COUNT(*) AS `orders_counts`
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY `userId`
  HAVING `order_counts` >= 3
) AS oc
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT `userId`, COUNT(*) AS `bonuses_counts`
  FROM `bonuses`
  GROUP BY `userId`
) AS bc ON bc.userId = oc.userId AND oc.orders_counts >= bc.bonuses_counts
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. А можно как-то подзапросы записать в переменные?